# $B = \{\{x\}|x\in X\}$ Prove B is a basis for a topology on $X$

Tags: general-topology

Say $X$ is a set and we know $\mathcal{B} = \{\{x\}|x\in X\}$.

I'm trying to show that:

(a) $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for a topology on $X$

(b) that $\mathcal{B}$ generates the discrete topology.

The criteria for a basis are:

For each $x\in X$ there is some $B\in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x\in B$

For any $B_1$,$B_2 \in \mathcal{B}$ and any $x \in B_1 \cap B_2$, there is some $B \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in B⊆B_1\cap B_2$.

For part (a), I'm honestly somewhat lost. $\mathcal{B}$ is the set of points, so there must be subsets that have fewer points than $\mathcal{B}$, but how do I know if the second criterion for a basis applies without knowing the size of a subset?

For part (b), I know that the discrete topology is the largest topology containing all subsets as open sets. Assuming that I know part (a)  has given me the basis for a topology:

We have a collection of all one-point subsets on $X$, which is the basis for the discrete topology by definition.

Proving if $X$ is discrete then every set of one element is open is easy. If $X$ is discrete, we know this by definition.

I'm less sure how to prove *$X$ is discrete because all of the one-point subsets are open*. I would guess that you would take some arbitrary set in $X$, something like $U$, and say that $U = \bigcup_{u \in U}\{u\}$. Then you know it's a union of open sets. Because it was arbitrary, $X$ only contains open sets and must be discrete.

Comment: sizes of subsets are irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (a) just note that for any $x \in X$ we have $x \in \{x\} \in \mathcal{B}$. That's all for the first. The second criterium is trivial, as $x \in B_1 \cap B_2$ immediately  implies that $B_1  = B_2 = \{x\}$ (as both sets only have one element, and it must be $x$) so if that happens we just take $B_3 = \{x\}$ too.

For (b): the topology generated by $\mathcal{B}$ is **by definition** the set of all unions of members of $\mathcal{B}$ and any $A \subseteq X$ is such a union: $A = \bigcup \{\{x\}\mid x \in A\}$. So the generated topology is just the power set of $X$, i.e. the discrete topology.

This whole exercise is a set-theory triviality.

Comment: This whole exercise is practicing the definitions.

Comment: @Arthur There *is* nothing to practice as both conditions are trivial.

Comment: Sure there is. What is a basis, what is a topology, what is the discrete topology? You and I have practiced these so much it doesn't even register to us as conscious thought, but for beginners, this is exactly the kind of exercise usually given to get their toes wet. And many do struggle, precisely because they don't have the definitions engraved in their fingertips, and they don't know where to even begin.

Answer (score 1):

If $x\in X$, then $x\in\{x\}$ and $\{x\}\in\mathcal B$. Now, if $B_1,B_2\in\mathcal B$, then either $B_1\cap B_2=\emptyset$, in which case there is nothing to check, or $B_1\cap B_2\ne\emptyset$. But in this case, since each element of $\mathcal B$ is a set with a single element, that can only happen when, for some $x\in X$, $B_1=B_2=\{x\}$. And then, if you take $B=\{x\}$, you have, $x\in B\subseteq B_1\cap B_2$.

Now, if $O$ is an element of the discrete topology, then$$O=\bigcup_{x\in O}\{x\}\in\mathcal B.$$Therefore, $O$ belongs to the topology generated by $O$. And if $O$ belongs to the topology generated by $O$, then $O$ belongs to the discrete topology, since this topology consists of all subsets of $X$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with (a).

The first criteria for a basis is a universal statement: $\forall\ x\in X,\ \exists B\in \mathcal{B}:x\in\mathcal{B}$. To prove a universal statement, we pick an arbitrary element from the universe and show that it's true for that one. Here, we want to prove something for every $x$ in $X$, so let $x\in X$. We know that $\{x\}\in\mathcal{B}$. Since $x\in\{x\}$, we have proven the first statement.

The second criterion is where you're hung up, but it's not much different. Let $B_1,B_2\in\mathcal{B}$ and suppose $x\in B_1\cap B_2$. There are a couple of ways to proceed, but here's one way. We need to come up with a $B\in\mathcal{B}$ that contains $x$ and is a subset of $B_1\cap B_2$. Remember that we know what the elements of $\mathcal{B}$ look like: they're singleton sets. Again, we've got a great candidate for a basis element that contains $x$...the singleton $\{x\}$. Does that contain $x$? Absolutely. Is it a subset of $B_1\cap B_2$? Well, we know that $x\in B_1$, so $\{x\}\subseteq B_1$. And $x\in B_2$, so $\{x\}\subseteq B_2$. Hence, $\{x\}\subseteq B_1\cap B_2$. So $B=\{x\}$ does the job again.

Another way to reason would be to say that if $B_1$ is a basis element that contains $x$, it must be $\{x\}$, since that's the only *basis* element that contains $x$ (there are plenty of open sets that contain $x$, but only one *basis* element that contains $x$). The same is true for $B_2$, so $B_1\cap B_2=\{x\}$ is already a basis element.

Now for (b). We can prove that two topologies are the same if they're finer than each other...that is, if they're subsets of each other. And your ideas here are spot on. In the Discrete Topology, every imaginable subset is open. So if you give me an open set from the topology generated by $X$, it must be an open set in the Discrete Topology. And just like you've said, if you give me an open set in the Discrete Topology (that is, literally any subset of $X$), then the union you've provided is a union of basis elements in $X$, which are open sets in the topology generated by $X$, so it must be open. Great insight!

Hope this helps.